# Python. Flask. Получить путь загружаемого файла

Tags: python, flask

Имеется вот такой код, загружающий на сервер файлы с расширением doc и docx через drag and drop. Необходимо "вытащить" **локальный путь файла**, который был залит на сервер:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['doc', 'docx'])
app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = "uploads"

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route("/sendfile", methods=["POST"])
def send_file():
    fileob = request.files["file2upload"]
    print(fileob)
    if allowed_file(fileob.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(fileob.filename)
        save_path = "{}/{}".format(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename)
        fileob.save(save_path)
    else:
        print('не то расширение')

    return "successful_upload"
```

Comment: локальный путь на сервере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кратко: никак.

Длинно: в целях защиты это запрещено. Браузеры заменяют на `C:\fakepath\very_important_document.docx`. А по факту документ может быть загружен на планшете, телефоне, с сетевого диска или система вообще может не иметь ФС с путями.

PS: Есть отдельные редкие хаки - но их работоспособность сомнительна и сильно зависит от браузера и версии. К примеру: [`mozFullPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/mozFullPath).

Comment: Спасибо за информацию!